# My pushpins in bingmaps for WP7 are all black. Why?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, maps, bing-maps

I am trying to work with WP7 and Bingmaps.

I have this code

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <my:Map Height="389" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,28,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="409" />
</Grid>
```

and

```
    public MapInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        GeoCoordinate lHamburg = new GeoCoordinate(53.550556, 9.993333);

        //map1.Radius = 5000;
        map1.ZoomLevel = 10.0;
        map1.Center = lHamburg;
        map1.CredentialsProvider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider(APPLICATION_ID);

        //Add a pin to the map
        Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
        Location location = new Location();
        location.Latitude = 53.550556;
        location.Longitude = 9.993333;
        pushpin.Location = location;

        map1.Children.Add(pushpin);
    }
```

But my pushpin is black, without any style.
Did I forget something?

Thanks,
Oscar

Edit: it looks like that they ARE black. I would have to set some style to it or something like that. Anyone could give me some hints of how to add a simple style? Very simple, maybe only change the color, or make it round like google maps or something like that.

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: They are styled that way to mourn the loss of personal privacy in the gps/smartphone age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following MSDN exercise will provide you with all the information that you need: [Exercise 2: Handling and Customizing Pushpins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic3). Scroll down to item 5 which is where the customizations of pushpins begins.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply! I will take a look at it as soon as I have some time!

Comment: I tried the link and the page appears to have moved. As best I can tell it is now at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic3#_Toc307127973

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger Thanks for the info. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a style for example:

```
<Style TargetType="my:Pushpin">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="White" />
</Style>
```

or directly set color while creating them:

```
    //Add a pin to the map
    Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
    Location location = new Location();
    location.Latitude = 53.550556;
    location.Longitude = 9.993333;
    pushpin.Location = location;
    pushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    map1.Children.Add(pushpin);
```

[**NOTE**: I used background property here. You may need to set different property/properties to change it's appearance to needed state.]

Comment: Hi,
Thanks! Very simple and easy solution! Thanks!

Comment: This answer, good as it is, doesn't address the real problem: the OP doesn't seem to understand that you can restyle or even change *all* the markup for *any* control in Silverlight or WPF. Once *that* sinks in, not only is the above perfectly obvious, but you will realise that you could use elaborate markup and even databinding.